# System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file/file'

Tags: c#, exception, .net

I have a little problem when i try to upload my data and a image.

the problem is:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyWebSites\Class\OriginalImages\IMG_9209.JPG' because it is being used by another process. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) at Admin_InsertStudent.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

**C#:**

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using System.Web.UI.WebControls; using System.IO; using System.Text;

public partial class Admin_InsertStudent : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string tempPath = "OriginalImages";
            string imgPath = "StudentImages";
            string savePath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, tempPath);
            string TempImagePath = Path.Combine(savePath, FileUpload1.FileName);

            string imgSavePath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, imgPath);
            string StudentImageNormal = Path.Combine(imgSavePath, FileUpload1.FileName);
            string StudentImageThumbnail = Path.Combine(imgSavePath, "t__" + FileUpload1.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            switch (extension.ToLower())
            {
                case ".png":
                    goto case "Upload";
                case ".gif":
                    goto case "Upload";
                case ".jpg":
                    goto case "Upload";
                case "jpeg":
                    goto case "Upload";

                case "Upload":
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(TempImagePath);

                    ImageTools.GenerateTumbnail(TempImagePath,StudentImageNormal, 400, 300, true, "High");

                    ImageTools.GenerateTumbnail(TempImagePath, StudentImageThumbnail, 120, 90, true, "medium");

                    lblMessage.Text = "Billedet" + FileUpload1 + "er nu uploadet";

                    string FirstName = Convert.ToString(txtFirstName.Text);
                    string MiddleName = Convert.ToString(txtMiddelName.Text);
                    string LastName = Convert.ToString(txtLastName.Text);
                    string BirthDay = Convert.ToString(txtBirthDay.Text);
                    string City = Convert.ToString(txtCity.Text);
                    string Pic = "OriginalImages/StudentImages/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
                    string WebSite = Convert.ToString(txtWebSite.Text);

                    break;

                default:
                    lblMessage.Text = "Denne Filetype er ikke tilladt";
                    return;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = err.ToString();
    }
        } }
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After uploading a file you have to release it.**

```
yourFile.Dispose();
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Use this method to close or release unmanaged resources such as files,
>   streams, and handles held by an instance of the class that implements
>   this interface. This method is, by convention, used for all tasks
>   associated with freeing resources held by an object, or preparing an
>   object for reuse.